# Arrays.binarySearch() returns wrong insertion point

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search

This is the code:

```
public class Main {

    public static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        int arr[] = {10,50,999,1000};
        int index = Arrays.binarySearch(arr,55);
        System.out.println(index);
    }
}
```

The output here is '-3', if the output from this formula "(-(insertion point) - 1)" that means the insertion point is '4' and that is not right.

So what i am missing?

Comment: Nope insertion point = 2, `(-2-1) = -3`, so the value SHOULD be at index 2, after the 10 and the 50

Comment: I think you should work on understanding java and the algorithms used rather than concluding too fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The insertion point is `2`, not `4`.

According to the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(int%5B%5D,int)):

> The **insertion point** is defined as the point at which the key would be inserted into the array: the **index** of the **first element greater** than the key [...]

Your array with indices is

```
[10, 50, 999, 1000]
  0   1    2     3
```

The first element greater than `55` is `999` at index `2`. Remember that indices start counting at `0`.

So the insertion point is `2`. With the formula `(-(insertion point) - 1)` the return value must thus be:

```
(-(2) - 1) = -3
```

Which is exactly what you got.

Answer (score 0):

There is no missing.`Array.binarySearchs` Returned index of the search key, if it is contained in the array; otherwise, (-(insertion point) – 1). The insertion point is defined as the point at which the key would be inserted into the array: the index of the first element greater than the key, or a.length if all elements in the array are less than the specified key. Note that this guarantees that the return value will be >= 0 if and only if the key is found.
this describtion is from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arrays-binarysearch-java-examples-set-1/).